# c - Passing a structure variable to a function : segfault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

### Context

Here is my code

```
typedef struct {
    int m;
    int (*v)(int *restrict a);
} polo;

int toto(int *restrict a){
    printf("hello %d\n",*a);
}
int main()
{

    polo *kilo;
    kilo->m = 84;
    kilo->v = toto;

    kilo->v(&kilo->m);

    return 0;

}
```

### Problem

Segfault.
I cannot get why. The same code works if kilo is not a pointer anymore. (polo kilo; kilo.m=...).

Could you explain me please ?

Thanks

Comment: you did not allocate any memory for the pointer

Comment: I added a point to all the other relevant answers. Thanks you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reserve space for `kilo`:

`polo *kilo = malloc(sizeof(*kilo));`

or

`polo *kilo = malloc(sizeof(polo));`

Don't forget to call `free(kilo);` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You should allocate memory before using a pointer.

You can do this:

```
polo *kilo = malloc(sizeof(polo));
```

or

```
polo temp;
polo *kilo = &temp;
```

And then the rest of the code will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate the memory for Pointer `kilo`.

```
int main()
{

polo *kilo;
kilo = malloc(sizfof(polo)); 
kilo->m = 84;
kilo->v = toto;

kilo->v(&kilo->m);
free(kilo);
return 0;

}
```

Without allocation of memory for Structure pointer you can't store the value's in structure member.

But When you declare `polo kilo;`, it doesn't  need memory allocation. Because you are declared a structure variable. when you are declaring structure variable, the memory os allocated for it statically. so it will work!

Answer (score 0):

The value of an uninitialized local (non-static) variable is *indeterminate*, using such a variable (except for initialization) leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which can lead to crashes.

The problem here is that you declare `kilo` to be a pointer, but you don't make it point anywhere. In fact, there's really no use to make it a pointer in the first case, just declare it as a normal non-pointer variable:

```
polo kilo;
kilo.m = 84;
kilo.v = &toto;

kilo.v(&kilo.m);
```

Tip of the day: Avoid using pointers as much as you can, they are a great source of problems unless care is taken.

Answer (score 0):

`polo *kilo;`  - the kilo pointer to polo is defined, but points anywhere.

`kilo->m = 84` - you attemt to write 84 to a random address. SEGFAULT.